# Identifying the reason the same ASP VBScript code runs at two different speed on two seperate machines

Tags: mysql, performance, vbscript, asp-classic

I was hoping for some guidance in this respect. I have the same set of ASP VBScript code running on two separate machines. The new machine has a better CPU (and more cores), 10 times the amount of RAM and an SSD hard drive (whereas the original was a standard Western Digital drive). Both machines have the same OS running IIS and MySQL.

However where the initial machine (which is 5 years old) will complete the processing of files (200 files) with multiple file reads, multiple database deletes, inserts and selects in under 2 hours, the seconds (far gutsier machine) takes 5 hours.Both machines are running the identical MySQL, IIS, Python and ASP code.

The CPU on the new machine is not burdened (sits idle at 2%), the RAM is not over utilized in any way (under 10% utilization). The code runs in series and doesn't run in parallel threads.

I was hoping for some guidance as to where to investigate the cause without having to rewrite multiple lines of code for better efficiency to try squeeze a second here and a second there. The resources on the new machine are not being utilized at all but I am feeling rather lost in the dark as to how to navigate this and hours of Google searches haven't yielded many positive solutions.

Comment: Sorry, to add to the above for clarity. On the old machine one of the functions which reads a CSV file, inserts the contents to MySQL, would take 3 seconds, on the new machine it would take 9 seconds. DB is the same, IIS is the same, new machine is stronger on performance capabilities. Have been spending a lot of time reading articles but so far frustrated and needing some guidance.

Comment: Compare the `my.cnf` files; list the diff here.